# Protect js-assets in a next.js / vercel project

Tags: next.js, middleware, assets

I have a next.js app, which is hosted on Vercel.
I want to dynamically load some components into my app. Only authenticated users should be able to load the component. The protection should include all generated js assets (static/chunks etc...).

I was able to enforce the component code splitting by abusing a wrapper page for this. I created a page and put just a component in it:
**pages/protected-component.js:**

```
import { ProtectedComponent } from 'some-package/component'


export default function ProtectedComponentWrapper() {
  return < ProtectedComponent />
}
```

**pages/index.js:**

```
function LoggedIn(props) {
  let state = props.state
  let set_state = props.set_state
  const ProtectedComponent = dynamic(() => import('./protected-component.js'), {
    suspense: true,
  })

  return (
    <ProtectedComponent/>
  )
}
```

This will generate seperate js files for ProtectedComponent. My plan is to have a custom middleware, where I check, that the user is authenticated and either deliver the js file or redirect the user to a login page.
My problem is that next is not generating one well-known js asset for ProtectedComponent. It generates ~10 files with this naming pattern `static/chunks/[shorthex]-[longhex].js` The hex numbers are generated at build time (I guess by web pack). They are stored in a file called `build-manifest.json`. I must make my middleware aware ofthese filenames. I cannot simple load the manifest file. That fails because filesystem is not available for edge runtime.
How can I achieve this for my middleware? Any other solution, that generates a well known js asset for the splitted module would be welcome, too.

TLDR:
What I basically need:
Code splitting on js module level.
A way to protect all the js assets which belong to a splitted module behind an authentication mechanism. Focus is on the asset protection not the concert authentication mechanism.